# Not allowing me to use a > between a function and int

Tags: python

## GUESSING GAME

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

def get_user_guess():
  guess = int(input('What is your guess: '))
  return guess

def roll_dice(number_of_sides):
  first_roll = randint(1, number_of_sides)
  second_roll = randint(1, number_of_sides)
  max_val = number_of_sides * 2
  print ("The maximum value you can roll is %d" % max_val)
  get_user_guess()
  if get_user_guess > 13:
    print ("invalid guess, please try again")
  else:
    print ("Rolling...")
    sleep(2)
    print ("%d" % first_roll)
    sleep(1)
    print ("%d" % second_roll)
    sleep(1) 
    total_roll = first_roll + second_roll
    print ("%d" % total_roll)
    print ("Result...")
    sleep(1)
    if get_user_guess == total_roll:
        print ("Congratulations, you've won!")
    else:
        print ("sorry sucker, you lose!")
roll_dice(6)
```

Here is the code. I made a running version in python 2, but translating it to python 3 has been a headache. I have defined that get_user_guess, where guess = an int. But further down in the roll_dice section, after I have called on the previous function and its answer I'm getting error messages.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you access the return value of a function. You should assign the return value to a new name, then use that in the following comparisons.

```
guess = get_user_guess()
if guess > 13:
    print("invalid guess")
else:
    ...
    if guess == total_roll:
        print("Congratulations")
    else:
        print("sorry")
```

Comment: Thank you! I've recently just started putting my nose into this stuff, it seems like I have more problems overlooking the simple things. Will fix.

Answer (score 0):

So, this seems like a small logic error and a syntax error as well. First the syntax error. You're not really initializing or calling the function in the comparison by doing:

```
if get_user_guess > 12
```

rather than doing:

```
if get_user_guess() > 12
```

So there is nothing for the ">" operator to compare against.

Second, seeing as you're trying to reuse the variable for the next comparison.You will need to store it as well otherwise it would prompt the user again for a new value again. Note the changes in lines 13,14 and 28 will fix it:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

def get_user_guess():
  guess = int(input('What is your guess: '))
  return guess

def roll_dice(number_of_sides):
  first_roll = randint(1, number_of_sides)
  second_roll = randint(1, number_of_sides)
  max_val = number_of_sides * 2
  print ("The maximum value you can roll is %d" % max_val)
  guess = get_user_guess()
  if guess > 13:
    print ("invalid guess, please try again")
  else:
    print ("Rolling...")
    sleep(2)
    print ("%d" % first_roll)
    sleep(1)
    print ("%d" % second_roll)
    sleep(1) 
    total_roll = first_roll + second_roll
    print ("%d" % total_roll)
    print ("Result...")
    sleep(1)
    if get_user_guess == total_roll:
        print ("Congratulations, you've won!")
    else:
        print ("sorry sucker, you lose!")
roll_dice(6)
```